# How to implement setInterval with loop and onclick function correctly?

Tags: javascript

I learn Javascript, just trying to understand how to work with setInterval in different situations. 
Now I have problem situation, please someone explain me where is the mistake, and how to do it correctly.

Problem situation:

I want by click to get new coordinate from counter and console log it.
For example I click on a button, and console shows me that:
0 
after 2000 ms 1
after 2000 ms 2
after 2000 ms 3
and so on

for example we have a function that do something with coordinates, just console log it's enough:

```
var showUs = function(coordinate){

console.log(coordinate)
}
```

another function is a counter that increase it:

```
var increase = function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < 50; i+=1){
       showUs(i);
     }
  }
```

and the last is the function that should shows coordinate with interval:

```
somebuttom.onclick = function(){

   setInterval(function(){ increase() }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, as we're lacking the context of what you're trying to do

Comment: soryy, I did edit my post: I want by click to get new coordinate form counter and console log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed your update. If you want to do it that way then try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2bmsxn7y/1/)

```
var somebutton = document.getElementById('somebutton');

var showUs = function(coordinate){

console.log(coordinate)
}

var increase = function(){
    var i = 0;
    var si = setInterval(function(){
        if(i < 50){
             showUs(i);
             i++;
        }else{
             clearInterval(si);   
        }
    }, 2000);
}

somebutton.onclick = function(){
  increase();
}
```

Comment: I want by one click console log next 50 numbers from the loop. By can't to understand how.